# Images not being responsive to screen width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my staff website , I have created a row of images successfully, but when I change the browser window size, the images don't go into one neat row, they mesh together and one picture disappears:
Any help?

Also, the code I'm using is here: https://github.com/Studio-Dracocoa/studio-dracocoa.github.io/blob/master/staff.html

Comment: Could you post a pen or a fiddle so we can visually see what the issues are?

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource.

Comment: Sorry all, stackoverflow didn't let me post two links. Here: https://studio-dracocoa.github.io/staff.html @NathanTuggy

Comment: Whoops, also @matthewelsom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this style to your `<img>`'s to prevent them from "meshing" together:

`img{ max-width: 100%; }`

I added a bit of margin below as well

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oergu0vp/1/).

**UPDATE**

Change your bootstrap `col` from `col-md-4` to `col-xs-6 col-md-4` and it should fix the disappearing.

**UPDATE 2**

To get them in a column for a smaller view change the bootstrap classes `col-xs-6 col-md-4` to this `col-xs-12 col-md-4`.

Then because all your `<img>`'s are absolute positioned they won't stack because absolutely positioned content does not take up space in the DOM so they will all lay on top of each other.  To fix this you can set you `bottom` img to `position:relative;` so it takes up space and can be stacked. I also added a `top:0;` style to the `.top` class to keep it anchored to the top left corner.

See this updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oergu0vp/8/) for a demo (resize the frame window to see it work).

Also, you should probably change the `#biop` divs to class `.biop` and update your styles accordingly. Ids should be unique for each element. Classes are used for multiple elements. You have 2 divs with the id `biop` which is invalid.

Comment: The meshing problem is fixed, but the images are still disappearing: https://studio-dracocoa.github.io/staff.html

Comment: It works! Sorry if I ask too much, but is it possible for the thumbnails to go in one row then all in the same column @zgood?

Comment: @Startomas See my update 2 for the column thumbnails

Comment: @Startomas I updated my fiddle number 2 a couple times to fix some issues I had noticed, but it should be solid now ;)

Comment: Thank you so much @zgood! Also, thanks for the explanation so I can learn from my mistake! :D

Comment: @Startomas no problem. Also, if you want to get them in the center you can use the bootstrap `col-n-offset-n` helper classes. Look at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gut53s5f/1/) for an example of this (the divs above the `.biop` divs).